# normalizing facecolor values in 4d graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now, so i'm reaching out for help here.

I'm trying to visualize 4 dimensional data: x,y,z coordinates coupled with a measurement value v.
The v values have been measured on a sheet in 3d space and I want to visualize this with the surface plot function and facecolors.
When the graph is plotted however, the colors do not resemble the correct normalized values of the data. I think I am missing some normalizing of the colors before running the surface plot.

The posts I found on this site are related to the coloring of z data in a 3d graph.

A second error I found is the fact that the ylist has 2 entries but I can only see an uniform layer and not two different values. When adding more datapoints in the ylist, this problem however seemed to go away.

any help is appreciated!

The code I currently run is as followed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import ma
import matplotlib        as mpl
from matplotlib import ticker, cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D;
from scipy import interpolate

plt.interactive(True);
xlist = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600]
ylist = [500,600]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)

A =[[9.72,9.65,10.2,9.6,10.46,9.54,9.41,9.53,10.02,9.6,9.36,9.51,9.56,9.89,10.47,11.5],[9.87,10.16,10.22,10.17,10.09,10.15,10.15,10.7,10.18,9.96,10.25,10.27,9.72,10.87,11.52,11.79]] 
B = [[10.3,9.93,10.24,10.17,10.1,10.02,9.72,9.96,10.8,9.81,10.12,10.4,10.74,10.98,11.27,11.69],[10.3,10.63,10.48,10.57,10.72,10.64,10.71,10.93,11.,10.53,10.51,10.73,10.96,10.82,11.08,12.08]]
C = [[10.2,10.26,10.7,10.37,10.82,10.32,10.3,10.29,10.61,10.53,10.48,10.96,11.02,11.31,11.55,12.04],[10.3,10.6,10.95,10.97,10.93,10.96,11.05,11.11,11.28,11.14,11.1,11.34,11.34,11.31,11.8,12.23]]
Z= np.zeros_like(X)

A -= np.min(A); A /= np.max(A);
B -= np.min(B); B /= np.max(B);
C -= np.min(C); C /= np.max(C);

fig = plt.figure()

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0., vmax = 12.23)

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d');
a=ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z+10,rstride=1, cstride=1, norm =norm, facecolors = cm.jet(A),shade=False); #aanmaken van surface op afstand z met x,y coordinaat en de waarde van V op dit (x,y,z) punt
b=ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z+15, rstride=1, cstride=1,norm =norm,facecolors = cm.jet(A),shade=False);
b=ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z+20, rstride=1, cstride=1,norm =norm,facecolors = cm.jet(A),shade=False);

cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet',30)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.linspace(0,12.23,12.23),boundaries=np.arange(0,12.23,.1))#plt.zlabel('z (mm)')

print(A)

plt.xlabel('x (mm)')
plt.ylabel('y (mm)')
plt.show()
```

[resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdJL7.jpg)

Comment: In yuor code `norm` is only used for the colorbar, but not for the surface plot colors.

Comment: wouldn't norm = norm in the arguments of the surface plot cover this?

Comment: No, you specify the facecolors explicitely.